# Weird characters formation caused by comment

Tags: support, comments

See the image

[image]

The box structure is caused by the comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47142259/regex-find-title-case-with-lower-case-articles-etc). Why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579844/how-does-zalgo-text-work

Comment: The zalgo text is "HE COMES", not the regex expression  He just copy/pasted it from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/17034).  Don't use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks intentional, to a degree.

The commentator intentionally put UTF-8 text in their comment to force the OP to think about UTF-8 text symbols (notably, this is called [Zalgo text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579844/how-does-zalgo-text-work)).  That much is *not* broken.

But this overshadows a larger problem:  XP is not supported anymore (by anyone; you are doing yourself incredible harm by running it today since if you get compromised, you're out of luck), and the older version of your browser isn't supported [by Stack Overflow itself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/175248).